# Preimage of these sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

if a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous everywhere and

$S_1= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ y>f(x) \}$,
$S_2 = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ y<f(x) \}$

Does $S_1 = f^{-1}((0,\infty))$ and $S_2 = f^{-1}((-\infty, 0))$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So using the standard definition,
$$f^{-1}((0,\infty))=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\,|\,f(x)\in(0,\infty)\}=
\{x\in\mathbb{R}\,|\,f(x)>0\}$$
and
$$f^{-1}((-\infty,0))=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\,|\,f(x)\in(-\infty,0)\}=
\{x\in\mathbb{R}\,|\,f(x)<0\}.$$

Since $S_1$ and $S_2$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and (for any set $C\subset\mathbb{R}$), $f^{-1}(C)$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, these sets cannot be equal.

Comment: I am trying to visualize these two sets $(S_1, S_2)$. Do they change with how we define a function $f$?

Comment: @Note yes they are entirely dependent on how we define $f$. If you imagine the line of your function $f$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $S_1$ is all of the area **above** $f$ and $S_2$ is all the area **below** f (see this [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tocdraw239)). However, these are points on the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ -- unlike the inverse-images, which are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: That's how I imagined it first. I am stuck trying to prove that $S_1$, $S_2$ are open $\iff f$ is continuous. So if I pick a point $(x,y) \in S_1$, how do I show that $(x-\delta, x+\delta)\times(y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon) \subset S_1$ since the epsilon-delta definition of continuity applies to points on the graph itself, and not to points in $S_1$. Because if $y=f(x)$ then $(x,y) \notin S_1$.

Comment: @Note continuity doesn't really have much to do with the question you posted, perhaps would be best for MSE organization to ask in a new post.